# How can I open a single app by an unidentified developer without allowing all

Tags: applications, macos

I know to secure safety it is now not allowed anymore to open apps that were not downloaded from the mac app store.

But surely there is a workaround for this to open an app that you know is 'good' but just isn't in the app store.
Preferably allowing only that app and not allowing all downloaded apps to be opened.

[image: screenshot]

How do I open an app that is not downloaded from the app store in mountain lion?

Comment: Good point! I wish that there were an option to manually allow a single app and not tear down the whole wall at once.

Comment: The edits make the question much more clear. Great work!

Comment: @gentmatt if you wish to make an allowance or exception without changing what's in System Preferences, try http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/58522/8546 … should we have a separate question?

Comment: @GrahamPerrin According to the accepted answer it's not necessary to change what we have in the System Preferences. I think the right-click option is very convient. Why do you want to post a separate question?

Comment: I had [a brief discussion](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5566746#5566746) with @gentmatt

Comment: I deleted my answer – on closer inspection, reviewing past and present test results, it's probably applicable to a different aspect of Gatekeeper. Not for this question.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can ignore the gatekeeper restrictions on a per-app basis by right/control-clicking and selecting "Open". And because the check is done only on the first open, you can run it normally afterwards.

More details in:

- [John Siracusa's review](http://arstechnica.com/apple/2012/07/os-x-10-8/15/) of Mountain Lion
- Apple article HT5290, [Mountain Lion: About Gatekeeper](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5290).

Comment: This method is actually Apple's official way of doing it.

Comment: @cksum do you have a link to the official apple way would be nice to include that in the answer.

Comment: @FLY Unfortunately not. The matter was discussed in a private testing area and as such, is still under Apple's NDA. But, I'm sure Apple will document the feature soon enough.

Comment: @FLY, open Help Center, search for "open an app from an unidentified developer". This method is listed there.

Comment: Is there a way to do this from a command line for a terminal application?

Answer (score 10):

To enable the execution of an app against the policy that you have set in System Preferences, then you can simply right click on the app in question, and click open.  This will produce a further "Are you sure?" check, but will allow you to open an app and over-rule your app signature settings without you needing to go into System Preferences each time.

Comment: An this has a permanent effect, right? If yes, that would be superb.

Comment: Apparently, once you have run an app, regardless of what method you use to authenticate it, it's signature get's added to the permitted list and you are able to run it again without requiring to re-authenticate/confirm etc.

Comment: I can confirm that this will always allow the app to run: [link](http://www.evernote.com/shard/s35/sh/c11836ba-a3a9-4274-8a06-c8ce954e810c/865df24bc168f7e1fdeeacb7d0e51f9a)

Answer (score 10):

Although Ctrl+Right Click might work for some people, it didn't for me. They key to fix it is open `Terminal.app` (under `/Applications/Utilities`) and type in

```
xattr -d com.apple.quarantine
```

then at the end press space and drag the application you are trying to open in there, so it should look like this (this is an example for Google Chrome):

```
xattr -d com.apple.quarantine /Users/username/Desktop/Google\ Chrome.app
```

(here *username* refers to the user account name)

Comment: I am looking in 2019 and ditto, and your solution works

Answer (score 6):

Disable gatekeeper just for one app:

```
sudo xattr -rd com.apple.quarantine /Applications/LockedApp.app
```

Disable gatekeeper for all apps:

```
sudo spctl --master-disable
```

Install your app, then enable it again:

```
sudo spctl --master-enable
```

You can check assessments status by typing:

```
sudo spctl --status
```

Comment: It is 2021 and your top example still works well. Saved me a headache.

Answer (score 2):

To enable a single unsigned app that you know to be safe, follow these steps:

1. Go to **System Preferences**, then **Security and Privacy**, then click "Anywhere"

   [image]
2. Launch the app. This will remove the "unsigned download" warning status from the app.
3. Return to **System Preferences** and return the Gatekeeper settings to the level you want (default is "Mac App Store and identified developers")

Your app should launch as desired, but future downloaded apps will be subject to Gatekeeper scrutiny.

Comment: hmm yes I see now... but I was looking to add the specific application to the 'white list'. But I guess this will have to do +1 for now if no one comes up with A better answer I'll accept this one.

Comment: @FLY I didn't realize you were looking to whitelist only a single app. See edits.