# How does data get "imported" into ML's new features?

Tags: macos, messages, reminders, notes.app, gatekeeper

I'm a little concerned about upgrading to Mountain Lion right now because I'm not sure how some of the data I have on my machine will get shoehorned into Mountain Lion's new apps and features.

- Does "Notes" start out clean? Does it import your To-Dos from Mail (the way Notes would sync before iOS 6/ML)? Or does it import notes from Stickies?
- What happens to all of my Reminders in iCal? Do they automatically get imported into the Reminders app? Will I end up with duplicate Reminders resultant from iCloud issues?
- I have the iChat setting turned on that saves all your chat logs. Will I still be able to open them in Messages? Will my iMessage conversations start to get saved in the same logs? (Is chat logging even still in the Messages app?)
- I know Gatekeeper is enabled automatically, so what happens to always-running processes that I have set to start when my Mac turns on? I don't know if apps like Dropbox, LogMeIn, f.lux, or any of the others that start up as soon as I boot my machine, are signed with an Apple Developer ID, so will this cause big issues when I update and all of these unsigned apps try to run at once? (I plan to disable Gatekeeper minutes after upgrading, but I don't want it to cause issues that might keep my machine from booting up at all.)

Comment: Please edit this down a bit - Gatekeeper doesn't (currently) interact with iCloud and the rest of the four questions would serve well to be asked and answered independantly (How does migration work? What data does Notes inherit? What data does Reminders inherit? What settings from iChat does Messages preserve?)

Comment: I haven't actually upgraded yet, but here's what I have read online: Your notes and reminders should be transferred properly, Messages does have logging and will open the old logs, and Gatekeeper whitelists all applications which are on your system at installation time.

Comment: Not sure about the others but Gatekeeper only relates to Installing apps, not running them.

Answer (score 1):

- Notes will import from the Notes folder in Mail. They no longer appear in Mail, but are still an IMAP folder.
- Reminders will import from the task calendars in iCal. They no longer appear in Calendar, but are still `ical` files.
- Messages pretty much *is* iChat, with a different UI and an extra protocol (i.e., iMessage, which is really just XMPP). You can still save logs. You can still read your iChat logs. If you have iChat set to load old conversations when a window opens, the iChat conversations will appear in Messages when you open it the first time.
- For Gatekeeper, most apps are signed already so you won't have to worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

The others I can only make educated guesses at, so I'll leave them for the moment, but Gatekeeper shouldn't cause any problems with existing programs. Gatekeeper doesn't check that an app has been signed properly on every launch, just the first launch, and then only if it's in the system's [quarantine](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3662?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US).

For more detail, check out the [Gatekeeper section](http://arstechnica.com/apple/2012/07/os-x-10-8/15/#game-of-gates) of the Ars Technica Mountain Lion review.

You may also want to consider keeping Gatekeeper on the default setting. You can ignore it on an individual basis by [right-clicking and selecting Open](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/58509/how-can-i-open-a-single-app-by-an-unidentified-developer-without-allowing-all/58520#58520). It does give you a bit of an extra margin for safety, just in case something goes awry.

Comment: Not sure about the others but Gatekeeper only relates to Installing apps, not running them.