# Mac security problems

Tags: install, security

I'm having a problem installing an application (vuze). I've gone into the regular settings tab and I can't find anywhere to change any particular setting.

I looked online and I just randomly see the same security tabs I found myself so...not sure what I have to change.

Any ideas as to what I have to change in order to install this app?

I'm new to the Mac game so not sure where I have to go.

Thanks in advance.

***Edit:***
The message I get is

> Your security preferences allow installation of only apps from the mac app store and identified developers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I open a single app by an unidentified developer without allowing all](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/58509/how-can-i-open-a-single-app-by-an-unidentified-developer-without-allowing-all)

Comment: @robmathers the answers to the post you link would be one way of answering this question, but this is a more general question than that one. Not a duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A feature of OS X Mountain Lion is the ability to run only signed applications - that is, applications from Apple's app store - out of the box.  This is a configurable setting, however, and can be changed in the settings screen you seem to have already uncovered.  If you set the "Allow applications downloaded from" option to "Anywhere", your Mac should run applications downloaded from the internet as well.

[image]

Do be aware of the security implications of this, and consider changing it only when necessary (and reverting the setting after you've installed the downloaded application which you trust).

For more information, and screen shots, see:
http://www.maclife.com/article/howtos/how_tweak_settings_gatekeeper_mountain_lion

Comment: thanks for the informative/illustrative response. Just got this mac so i get lost easily lol. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Additionally, if you only want to run this one app at the moment, and leave the settings alone, Right Click on the app in the Finder and select Open.